# what does AllowOverride ALL mean in kohana .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, kohana

I´ve just installed kohana v3.1.4 "fasciinucha" STABLE from here (http://kohanaframework.org/download) and have a question about .htaccess. If I change example.htaccess to just .htaccess as recommended, I get this error "Internal Server Error".so I fixed this by changing

"AllowOverride AuthConfig" to "AllowOverride All" in the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default in the  part.

Could anyone explain the following?

1. what does the "ALL" refer to? could this be a security risk? who is "all"?
2. In my Kohana .htaccess file I can change the RewriteBase path to either / or /kohana/ It doesn´t make any difference?..why is this?

thanks for any help,

yours,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

1. Due to [Apache 2.0 docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) AllowOverride option's context is Directory. Don't know why this option presents in .htaccess file. 
   Anyway, AllowOverride options tells Apache which directives declared in `.htaccess` file can override earlier configuration directives. `All` - any directive which has the .htaccess Context is allowed in .htaccess files. `AuthConfig` allows use of the authorization directives.
2. Because setting of site BASE is made in `/application/bootstrap.php` with `base_url` `Kohana::init()` config option in Kohana.

Comment: @2. ok..so setting this rewrite base again in .htaccess is superficial and ignored?

Comment: I'd not touch `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess` file, because it's assumed to be a part of framework and it's core. Due to Kohana Docs (http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Kohana#init) `'base_url' should be the relative path from your DOCROOT to your index.php file, in other words, if Kohana is in a subfolder, set this to the subfolder name`.